# I have to classify user statements in 30 categories using svc ..So What should be done

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, python-3.7, svc

I want to solve this problem using ml algorithm of svc.
The problem is: "I have 2 columns 1 for sentences and other for the category of that statement. So what I want to do is make a model which classifies the user statements into 30 categories"

Comment: I vote this question to be closed since it needs more clarity and detail.

Comment: Basically i am trying to to make a model which classifies user utterances into 31 categories or class

Comment: And it is not clased

Comment: Please provide your code, your data (at least a toy example) and clarify the problem you have.

Comment: i do not have code...i can give u a sample data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok i ll first learn to ask ...then i ll post my questions here